# Writing Gatt Server Application in Bluez

Tags: linux, bluetooth, makefile, bluez, gatt

We want to write a custom **Gatt Server** Application for **Bluez** where we want to give some useful features. For example:

1. Start Gatt Server
2. Register/Unregister custom Service
3. Add/Remove custom Characteristics/Descriptor
4. Set/Get Value of Characteristics/Descriptor
5. Disconnect Client / Close Gatt Server etc.

Bluez don't have these features in command line tool but they have several APIs (functions) to do that, we need to call those internal functions.
In according to that we wrote an application in **"bluez5.28/attrib/"** directory from where we called several internal functions from files of
**"bluez5.28/attrib/"**, **"bluez5.28/profiles/"** and **"bluez5.28/src/"** directories and tried to build it with **bluez** **Makefile**.

Since bluez have automated generated make file from automake it is quiet hard to make any change in that Makefile. But when we tried it showed lots of errors
regarding dependencies and libraries e.g. undefined references, no such files of directories, etc.

**Is their any easier way to use bluez functions to make a GattServer Application ?**

Thanks in advance for your valuable answers.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bluez gatt dbus apis are now complete as of version 5.29. You may consider using those if going via the dbus rather than directly through library calls is acceptable for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Seeing your post, I found the release of 5.29. In the release they said dbus gatt apis are documented in doc/gatt-api.txt. I have downloaded bluez5.29 tar ball but found gatt-api.txt is missing.
** Can you please give a brief tutorial how can I use bluez gatt-dbus apis ? and use above features mentioned in the questions.

Comment: The doc can be found here: http://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt?id=5.29. Sorry, I can't write a tutorial at this time. That would be a good thing to do but I don't have the time for that at the moment. Read the doc and see how you go. If you have specific questions then please post them.

Comment: @AlanAu Is it possible right now to use the library directly ? I am not able to compile my own gatt server out of bluez tree right now. Make install does not provide headers and function in library for gatt dev.

Comment: GATT D-Bus API is not defined as experimental from Bluez v5.42: http://www.bluez.org/release-of-bluez-5-42/  
Its API is defined here: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt

There is a python example you can inspire yourself to write your GATT Server application: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-gatt-server

Answer (score 0):

correlate pg:1950 in bluetooth spec4.0 APPENDIX: EXAMPLE ATTRIBUTE SERVER

ATTRIBUTES  with gatt-example.c in plugins in bluez5.28